# gridview update with dynamically created textboxes

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview that is bound to a sql data source.

In the RowBound method I have this code in order to format the editable textboxes:

```
protected void gridview_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //Format the Edit row.
        if (e.Row.RowIndex == gridview.EditIndex && e.Row.RowIndex >= 0)
        {
           //Add Ajax Calendar to Date fields
            TextBox startDate= ((TextBox)e.Row.Cells[7].Controls[0]);
            startDate.ID = "txtStartDate";
            TextBox endDate= ((TextBox)e.Row.Cells[8].Controls[0]);
            endDate.ID = "txtEndDate";
            startDate.Attributes.Add("onchange", "javascript:GridviewAutoCalculateEndDate(this, " + endDate.ClientID + ");");

            AjaxControlToolkit.CalendarExtender startDateCalendar = new AjaxControlToolkit.CalendarExtender();
            startDateCalendar .ID = "startDateCalendar ";
            startDateCalendar .TargetControlID = "txtStartDate";
            startDateCalendar .Format = "dd/MM/yyyy";
            AjaxControlToolkit.CalendarExtender endDateCalendar = new AjaxControlToolkit.CalendarExtender();
            endDateCalendar.ID = "endDateCalendar";
            endDateCalendar .TargetControlID = "txtEndDate";
            endDateCalendar .Format = "dd/MM/yyyy";

            e.Row.Cells[7].Controls.Add(startDate);
            e.Row.Cells[8].Controls.Add(endDate);
            e.Row.Cells[7].Controls.Add(startDateCalendar );
            e.Row.Cells[8].Controls.Add(endDateCalendar );
        }
}
```

The above just adds a dynamic AjaxCalendarExtender to two textboxes and the javascript, takes the date entered in the startDate textbox, adds one year to it and updates it in the endDate textbox (so you do not have to change it manually).

The problem I am having is that when I click the Update command field, I get a null reference to those two textboxes and the text inside them also clears (something to do with postback?)

Here is the update code:

```
protected void gridview_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    DateTime startDate= new DateTime();
    DateTime.TryParseExact(e.NewValues[6].ToString(), "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal, out startDate);
    DateTime endDate= new DateTime();
    DateTime.TryParseExact(e.NewValues[7].ToString(), "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal, out endDate);

    dataContext.UpdateDates(startDate, endDate);
    PerformDataBind();
}
```

Basically startDate and endDate seem to clear and become null right after clicking Update. The e.NewValues don't seem to pull the date fields.
If I am to remove the dynamic data they update just fine.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### What's happening:

Dynamically created controls must be created each and every time the Page loads. When you press the Update button, a PostBack occurs, and in that PostBack you'd have to recreate the dynamic controls to be able to access them.

Meaning, if `RowUpdating` is happening, and you didn't go through `RowDataBound` before, the controls are not there.

I also presume that during an `Updating` PostBack, `gridview.EditIndex` will have a different value, so your controls won't be there in any case.

### What you should be doing instead:

You should design your edit mode template in your markup, and let ASP.NET handle control creation. Take advantage of the data binding capabilities, let them do the work for you.

Comment: I understand the edit mode template. I have used them before where I had used a static sqldatasource to populate the gridview but in this instance I am binding the data source via stored procedure based on the user's search.  `gridview.DataSource = dataContext.GetRecords(searchParameter);
        gridview.DataBind();` where dataContext is a linqtosql structure. Can edit mode be enabled for such a configuration?

Comment: Or how can I assign the control IDs to the textboxes in the html code?

Answer (score 0):

The variable names "startDate" and "endDate" only exist within your if statement, if you want to adress them with that name define them in a higher scope

Comment: Sorry I forgot to copy that over. Updated above. But the result is the same.

Comment: I'm not that sure myself since i'm not that much into asp.net, but could it have to do with e.NewValues ? did you try with e.OldValues or gridview.Rows[e.RowIndex]?

Comment: e.OldValues is empty for some reason so it throws a null reference and I have tried gridview.Rows[e.RowIndex] which also comes back with null, as it seems that the dynamic code gets lost when clicking Update on the row. Does it do postback and THEN the update? Seems wrong